# Views delete the fields when saved

Tags: views

I have the site (multi site), it have Views, which displays a list of articles on a page.
When I try to change something in Views or add a new field, Views removes most of the existing fields .
When I try to import Views, it displays an error : 
"Field handler field_data_field_date.field_date is not available."
"Field handler field_data_field_news_type.field_news_type is not available." etc.
Every fields exist.

Someone saw this before ?
Thank you

Comment: date_views module might not be installed.

Comment: date_views module is active